# Not able to open firefox from selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

I am getting the below error when i am running the selenium script.

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
fTime":1409733904986}}},{"name":"winreg-app-user","addons":{"{e4f94d1e-2f53-401e-8885-681602c0ddd8}":{"descriptor":"C:\\ProgramData\\McAfee Security Scan\\Extensions\\{e4f94d1e-2f53-401e-8885-681602c0ddd8}.xpi","mtime":1396607774000}}},{"name":"app-profile","addons":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Users\\kishna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous3395727590319882631webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","mtime":1409812670363,"rdfTime":1409812670181}}}]
1409812670931   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database C:\Users\kishna\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous3395727590319882631webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1409812670931   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
```

Comment: What version of Firefox? What version of Selenium?

Comment: Firefox version = 32.0  and selenium-java-2.42.2

Comment: Considering it's a version of Firefox released a day or two ago, and considering there are a fair few changes in the DevTools & DOM engine, I highly suspect Selenium doesn't support this *yet*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/32 ...you'll need to give the Selenium development team time to support it - or dig out the code yourself and help them figure out what needs changing to support this version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox WebDriver doesn't work with Firefox 32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646639/firefox-webdriver-doesnt-work-with-firefox-32)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `selenium` version that doesn't support Firefox version 32.

And since currently there is no `selenium` java package version that claiming support for Firefox 32, you need to downgrade your browser. In your case, downgrade it to Firefox **28**, which is [listed as supported](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG) by selenium 2.42.2.

See also similar problem here:

- [selenium and web2py from killer-web-development.com doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654761/selenium-and-web2py-from-killer-web-development-com-doesnt-work/25654817#25654817)

Also see:

- [Where can I find a definitive Selenium WebDriver to Firefox Compatibility Matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358859/where-can-i-find-a-definitive-selenium-webdriver-to-firefox-compatibility-matrix)
- [Documentation confusion: what version of Firefox does Selenium support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364512/documentation-confusion-what-version-of-firefox-does-selenium-support)
- [Is Selenium 2.42.2 webdriver compatible with Firefox 27.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502927/is-selenium-2-42-2-webdriver-compatible-with-firefox-27-0-1)

Comment: I have changed firefox version from 32 to 31 and it worked . Thank You alecxe and aran . . .

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to 2.43.1 [http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/]. The new version works for FF32.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow link below in the future for check supported versions FF vs. WebDriver.
I use it if I want to update browser or webdriver library.

LINK: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG